# How to count Push notification bedge android

Tags: java, android, push-notification, notifications

The counter badge should be displayed on the notification icon from firebase. I don't know how to bring bedge to these, I tried many things but I didn't get any answer If you know anything let me know How to bring these to budget. I am getting errors. How to fix these counter icon show bedge

```
`public class MyFirebaseMessageService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onNewToken(@NonNull String token) {
    super.onNewToken(token);
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

      try {
        if(remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {

            final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
            Log.d(TAG,"remoteMessage = " + jsonObject.toString());
            
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onMessageReceived: ", e);
    }
 
       if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
        Log.d("onMessageFirebase: ", remoteMessage.getData().toString());

        if (data.get("post_id") != null) {
            String _unique_id = data.get("unique_id");
            String title = data.get("title");
            String message = data.get("message");
            String big_image = data.get("big_image");
            String link = data.get("link");
            String _post_id = data.get("post_id");

            assert _unique_id != null;
            long unique_id = Long.parseLong(_unique_id);

            assert _post_id != null;
            long post_id = Long.parseLong(_post_id);

            createNotification(unique_id, title, message, big_image, link, post_id);
        }
    }
}


private void createNotification(long unique_id, String title, String message, String image_url, String link, long post_id) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("unique_id", unique_id);
    intent.putExtra("post_id", post_id);
    intent.putExtra("title", title);
    intent.putExtra("link", link);

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.app_name);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon(notificationBuilder))
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_notification_large_icon))
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


    
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        notificationBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
    } else {
        notificationBuilder.setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    }

    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    notificationBuilder.setSound(alarmSound).setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400});

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, getString(R.string.app_name), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.shouldShowLights();
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.GREEN);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(false);
        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }

    if (image_url != null && !image_url.isEmpty()) {
        Bitmap image = fetchBitmap(image_url);
        if (image != null) {
            notificationBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(image));
        }
    }

    //assert notificationManager != null;
    notificationManager.notify((int) post_id, notificationBuilder.build());
}

private int getNotificationIcon(NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder) {
    notificationBuilder.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPrimary));
    return R.drawable.ic_stat_onesignal_default;
}

private Bitmap fetchBitmap(String src) {
    try {
        if (src != null) {
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(1200000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(1200000);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}`

how clear this error